# CakePHP 1.3 Error: Fatal error: Call to a member function cd() on a non-object in /var/www/html/projectname/cake/libs/cache/file.php on line 248

Tags: cakephp, fatal-error

When I install and give permission to whole CakePHP folder, it gives me below fatal error:

Server Configurations:
CakePHP 1.3.x version
PHP Version 5.3.6

Fatal error: Call to a member function cd() on a non-object in /var/www/html/xyz/cake/libs/cache/file.php on line 248

I tried to search on Google, but not much helpful.

Any idea, how to resolve this?

Regards !

Comment: Please print some of the logic that leads to this error, the controller action would be a good start.

Comment: this is only i get when i run my code..

Comment: @iamtheladylegend Yes, please post some of that code.  This way we can see what you're doing and we can better help you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

in your `/app/config/core.php` uncomment the date_default_timezone_set line

Comment: yes this helps.. i've added `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');` and it worked :) tnx